# Al usar (String.Format("{0:#-#-##}", item.codigo)) en un item de una lista, el orde by valor_id se pierde MVC C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

Tengo la siguienta vista que se encarga de mostrar el codigo en este format 9-9-99.
Y desde el controller le indico que venga ordenado por el código, que está guardado en entero:

```
<table id="listado_table " class="table table-striped table-bordered dt-responsive" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
<thead>
    <tr style="background-color:#ff6a00;color:#fff">
        <th>Codigo</th>
        <th>Nombre</th>
        <th>Acciones</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
 <tbody>
    <% foreach (var item in Model.listado)
       { %>
    <tr>
        <td>
           <div style="display:none"> <%: item.codigo%></div>
            <%:             


            (String.Format("{0:#-#-##}", item.codigo)) %> // aquí le colocó String.Format, y se pierde el orden

        </td>
        <td>
            <%:item.nombre %>
        </td>

        <td class="center-block">
            acciones
        </td>
    </tr>
    <% } %>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Pero cuando yo le coloco a ítem.codigo (String.Format("{0:#-#-##}", item.codigo)), hace que se pierda todo el orden item.codigo, pero cuando no tiene (String.Format("{0:#-#-##}", item.codigo)), viene ordenado. Me gustaría saber si hay alguna forma de ordenarlo en ese formato 9-9-99, sin que pierda el orden por codigo

En ese orden debería mostrarme cuando  con ese formato(le puse dentro del rectángulo rojo) 
[image: Como se debería mostrar]

Pero me lo muestra así:
[image: Me lo muestra desordenado el codgo con el String.Format]

Pero cuando le quito el String.Format, puedo verificar que vienen ordenado por código. 
[image: Ordenado el codigo sin el String.Format]

El problema es que se desordena cuando le pongo String.Format

Comment: ¿Puedes mostrar la lista? ¿Cuál es el orden que debería tener? ¿cuál es el resultado que deberías obtener? Si el número es el 9999 está bien el resultado 9-9-99. `String.Format` está realizando correctamente su trabajo.

Comment: si, la lista lo muestra, debe estar ordenado por codigo, de hecho lo está, pero cuando, porque la query viene con order by codigo, pero cuando le pongo String.Format, pierde el ordenamiento. Voy a editar la pregunta para especificar mas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ahora se entiende lo que **.Net** está haciendo. Gracias por aclarar con los pantallazos.

Lo que está pasando es que primero se restan las cifras, porque el signo `-` no lo reconoce como separador, sino como operador de resta.

Entonces:

```
1111 = 1-1-11 = -11
1200 = 1-2-00 = -1
1218 = 1-2-18 = -19
1233 = 1-2-33 = -34
1301 = 1-3-01 = -3
```

Ahora recién ordena:

```
-1  = 1-2-00
-3  = 1-3-01
-11 = 1-1-11
-19 = 1-2-18
-34 = 1-2-33
```

Lo que no se entiende es por qué ordena en forma ascendente en una y en forma descendente en otra.

También puede ser que esté ordenando sólo por la primera cifra, o sólo por las últimas dos.

En cualquier caso se me ocurren dos posibles soluciones:

- 1) Quitar el `Format` de la cláusula `Order By`
- 2) Solicitar un duplicado de la columna `Codigo`, para aplicar el `Order By` a una columna y el `Format` a la columna duplicada.

Comment: la solución 2 no mas, añadir un item oculto de codigo, para que se muestre ordenado, y asi a la vez muestro el formato que deseo, pero no era la idea colocar mas datos. :/